# How to get the Galois group for $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

For the real number field $\mathbb{R}$ and the rational number field $\mathbb{Q}$, how to get the Galois group ${\rm{Gal}}(\mathbb{R/Q})$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $f\in Aut_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{R})$.

**Hints:**

1) $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R} [a\leq b \rightarrow f(a)\leq f(b) ]$. To show this, note that $f(b)-f(a)=f(b-a)=f((\sqrt{b-a})^2)=f(\sqrt{b-a})^2\geq 0$

2) Let $x$ be any real number. Let $r_n$ be an increasing sequence of rationals that converge to $x$. we find that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} [r_n=f(r_n)\leq f(x)]$. By taking limits, we find that $x\leq f(x) $

3) Let $s_n$ be any decreasing sequence that converges to $x$. imitate the argument of step 2 to deduce that $x\geq f(x)$ for every real $x$

Thus, $f$ is the identity. Hence $Aut_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{R})$ is trivial.

Comment: very good，thanks a lot